# Convert string to int in tuple of both

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list containing of tuples of strings. There can be some digit strings which I'd like to convert to int.

Example. Actually, I have a list like:

```
 ex = [('20121001', '"3"', '"04"', '39840', '2', '19', '2385',
 '"FRTE"', '"Earth, LGO"', '"2.16M-2.21M"', '"GGHS 18 with extra"',
 '"2074-2404"', '129', '129', '0', '2', '4', '15\r'), ('20121001',
 '"3"', '"04"', '39840', '2', '20', '840', '"ERSA"', '"WLAN Router"',
 '"2.16M-2.21M"', '"Router with Switch"', '"2074-2404"', '129', '129',
 '0', '0', '9', '6\r')]
```

There are digits like `'20121001'` which I'd like to convert to int, '"3"' should be unchanged because it's a string.
How can we do this?

Comment: Calling `int()` on a string of digits converts it to an int. do you need more help than that?

Comment: Yes, but I can't do this on the whole list. At the end, I'd like the whole list with ints and strings. (not only ints, not only strings).

Comment: What you need to study is Try/Except.

Comment: What do you want the final value of `'"3"'` to be? A `str` or an `int`? Also what do you want the final value of `'"Earth, LGO"'` to be: unchanged, or `"Earth, LGO"`?

Comment: But `'"3"'` isn't a digit, it's a 5-character string representation of a 3-character string representation of an int.

Comment: Yes you're right sorry. That's why I deleted my comment ;)

Comment: I'm curious to know where you got that list. Are you trying to parse a CSV file? If so, then you should use `csv.reader` to solve some of the problems you have.

Comment: Now that you've deleted your comments, and haven't updated your question, I have no idea what the desired output is. Can you edit the question to show what you actually want to get? (And, if it's not obvious, explain what the rule is.)

Comment: It's in fact data out of a csv file. I also tried csv.Reader. But: the Problem is that I can't say manually what the delimiter / separator should be...

Comment: @DMan sure you can - you do that by specifying a [`dialect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) to the reader. You can also use the [`Sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) to auto-detect the dialect, or [register your own dialect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.register_dialect) if you're dealing with some exotic delimiters / quote characters - if you need help with that though, you best ask a new question.

Comment: If you're parsing a CSV file, you really should use the `csv` module, as Robᵩ and Lukas Graf imply, not my answer. You may still need to map a `safe_int` call over each row after getting the `reader` working, but don't do the extra `literal_eval` or anything else.

Comment: @LukasGraf I know it's another question, but could you please tell me how this works? 
I did this: 
with open('/tmp/test.csv') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
But yes...I can't specify the separator :/

Comment: @DMan scratch that, I actually overlooked the trivial way to specify the delimiter. Just specify the delimiter as keyword argument like in the example for [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader): `csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')` (if `;` is your delimiter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know about `try`/`except` and the `int` function, you should be able to write a `safe_int` function that returns `int(x)` if it succeeds and `x` if it doesn't.

---

Then, to call that function on every element in the tuple, you need to loop over the tuple—whether an explicit `for` statement, a comprehension, or a call to `map`. For example:

```
>>> ex = ('20121001', '"3"', 'Earth, LGO')
>>> new_ex = map(safe_int, ex)
```

In Python 2.x, this will give you a list; in 3.x, an iterator; if you need a tuple back, either way, the `tuple` function will convert it for you:

```
>>> new_ex = tuple(map(safe_int, ex))
>>> print(new_ex)
(20121001, '"3"', 'Earth, LGO')
```

---

But you apparently don't want to just handle just `'20121001'`, but also `'"3"'`. To do that, you need to first try to interpret the value as a string representation of some Python value, and then interpret the result of *that* as an integer. Something like:

```
def safe_int(value):
    try:
        return int(ast.literal_eval(value))
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

The `literal_eval` will turn `'20121001'` into the integer `20121001`, and the `int` on that will return it directly. The `literal_eval` will turn `'"3"'` into the string `'3'`, and the `int` on that will return the integer `3`. The `literal_eval` will turn `'"Earth, LGO"'` into the string `'Earth, LGO'`, but the `int` on that will fail, so you'll get the original (extra-quoted) string.

It's not actually clear here whether `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` or something different is what you want here. All of your examples happen to work with either one, but that isn't the point; what you really want to do is look at *what generated this code*, and write the appropriately corresponding code to reverse that. (Or, better, change the generating code to generate something more sensible in the first place, if possible…)

In fact, from your comments, it seems like what you're trying to reverse is CSV quoting. The way to do that is with the `csv` module, *not* by calling `literal_eval` on each value.

---

But you don't just have a tuple, you have a *list* of tuples. So you need a *nested* loop: for each tuple in the list, for each element in the tuple, intify if possible. For example (this time using comprehensions instead of `map`, just for variety):

```
>>> ex = [('20121001', '"3"', 'Earth, LGO'), ('20121001', '"3"', 'ERSA')]
>>> new_ex = [tuple(safe_int(x) for x in tup) for tup in ex]
>>> print(new_ex)
[(20121001, '"3"', 'Earth, LGO'), (20121001, '"3"', 'ERSA')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are tring to remove one level of stringification from each item in the tuples, then `ast.literal_eval` might work for you:

```
ex = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(i) for i in t) for t in ex]
```

The list comprehension follows the data structure you've listed. Each call to `ast.literal_eval` converts a string to a Python object: `'3'` becomes `3`; `'"3"'` becomes `"3"`.

Comment: But that's not what he's trying to do. He wants `"3"` to be `3`, and he wants `'"Earth, LGO"'` to stay `'"Earth, LGO"'`, and this will do the wrong thing for both examples (at least according to his comments).

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution is beautiful! But since I don't know ast, I prefered the solution with try-except.